# ServiceStack: Custom app settings not used in view

Tags: c#, database, view, servicestack, appsettings

I'm getting along quite nicely with ServiceStack, but ran into an issue which I can't currently work round. In my Global.asax.cs Configure() method, I declare a database based AppSettings as follows:

```
            // Create app settings, based on dictionary settings from central database
            Dictionary<string, string> configSettings = null;
            using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
            {
                configSettings = db.Dictionary<string, string>(db.From<ConfigSetting>());
            }
            var dicSettings = new DictionarySettings(configSettings);

            // Register app settings for injection
            container.Register<IAppSettings>(dicSettings);
```

This works great in code in which the AppSettings is injected:

```
public class RemoteEmailValidator : IEmailValidator
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

    public bool ValidEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || email.Length > 256)
            {
                return false;
            }

            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            string baseURL = AppSettings.Get("MailgunAPIBaseURL", "");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseURL))
            {
                // If we can't check email in-depth, then it's OK
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                client.BaseUrl = new Uri(baseURL);
                client.Authenticator =
                        new HttpBasicAuthenticator(AppSettings.Get("MailgunAPIUserName", ""),
                                                   AppSettings.Get("MailgunAPIPublicKey", ""));
                RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
                request.Resource = AppSettings.Get("MailgunAPIEmailValidationResource", "");
                request.AddParameter("address", email);

                var response = client.Execute(request);
                dynamic content = DynamicJson.Deserialize(response.Content);

                return content.is_valid == "true";
            }
        }
        catch { } // Suppress any errors, because email validation is nice to have

        return true;
    }
}
```

The values are retrieved from the database as you'd expect. However, when I try accessing AppSettings from a view, the values are returned from the web.config. E.g. in my register.cshtml:

```
string maxHouseholdMembers = HostContext.AppSettings.Get("MaxMembersPerHousehold", "20");
```

the value wasn't varying based on the value from the database, but was varying based on updating web.config. So, is there any additional config I need to do, to get my view to use the custom AppSettings I created in the global.asax.cs Configure() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer while I was actually posting the question. Just needed to add an extra line in the Configure() method:

```
            // Create app settings, based on dictionary settings from central database
            Dictionary<string, string> configSettings = null;
            using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
            {
                configSettings = db.Dictionary<string, string>(db.From<ConfigSetting>());
            }
            var dicSettings = new DictionarySettings(configSettings);
            AppSettings = dicSettings;
```

The final line (AppSettings = dicSettings) does the trick and overrides the standard AppSettings.

Comment: Yep you just need to set AppHost AppSettings, you don't need to register in the IOC as well since ServiceStack will register it if it doesn't exist